# Linux Python Pygame Cannot access /etc/alsa/alsa.conf

Tags: python, linux, pygame, midi, alsa

I'm trying to run a basic Pygame midi script consisting of the following:

```
import pygame, pygame.midi    

pygame.midi.init()    
print "Midi Devices " + str(pygame.midi.get_count())
```

And i get the following output.

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3009:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /etc/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default
Midi Devices 0
```

I found out that the alsa.conf file is in `/usr/share/alsa/` rather than `/etc/alsa/`, but I don't know how to get it to look for the file on the proper path.

EDIT: I forgot to mention this, but `/etc/alsa/` does not exist

Comment: Do you even have a software MIDI synthesizer (such as timidity or fluidsynth) running or a hardware one connected to your system?

Comment: I have a casio keyboard connected, so i expect it to be detected. I tried with timidity, but that wasn't detected either

Comment: Different distributions might put the files into different places. Did you install some package from a 'foreign' distribution?

Comment: as far as I'm aware of, no

Comment: the thing is, if I run `lsusb` or `amidi` in the terminal, it detects the keyboard, but when I try to detect with pygame, it says there are no midi devices...

Comment: It might be an old version of pygame that might have been compiled against an old version of ALSA.

Comment: I found the issue, turns out pygame was installed in the home/.local/ python directory and not globally, so it was all screwed up. works now

Comment: If the goal is to get sound out of the MIDI keyboard, then it may be better to use a Python package dedicated to MIDI in particular. If on the other hand the goal is to write a game, MIDI output is not the best bet anyway, as it won't work for everybody and if it works, it won't sound the same for everybody.

Comment: The point is to read input from a MIDI keyboard, process the input event to get the key's number and draw something on a canvas depending on the key you hit. Sound is irrelevant in this particular project, as the keyboard's embedded speakers are suficient. It's a school project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make a link with ln

```
$ man ln

SYNOPSIS
   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

In the 1st form, create a link to TARGET with the name LINK_NAME.  In the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the
       current directory.  In the 3rd and 4th forms, create links to each TARGET in  DIRECTORY.   Create  hard  links  by
       default,  symbolic  links  with  --symbolic.   By  default, each destination (name of new link) should not already
       exist.  When creating hard links, each TARGET must exist.  Symbolic  links  can  hold  arbitrary  text;  if  later
       resolved, a relative link is interpreted in relation to its parent directory.

Comment: problem is `/etc/alsa/alsa.conf` doesn't exist.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, create it.

Answer (score 3):

Pygame is searching 'alsa.conf' in the wrong location. You should create a soft link to it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf /etc/alsa/alsa.conf
```

At least that worked in [my case](https://github.com/FMMT666/launchpad.py).

Comment: It might be needed to create the `/etc/alsa` directory first with `sudo mkdir /etc/alsa`

Answer (score 0):

Let ALSA know the location of the config file with the environment variable:

```
export ALSA_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

This can be done in your profile (as a normal user), rather than needing to make a symlink (as root).

From the [list of environment variables](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/LibEnvVars):

> ALSA_CONFIG_PATH
>
> file to use instead of ALSA_CONFIG_DIR/alsa.conf

Setting `ALSA_CONFIG_DIR` would also work.